# How to prove these two things commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~ckent/spring2016/math343/hw9.pdf

I've done all of the homework but I'm stuck at the very end. In part 7d (it's really 6d, I don't know why he labeled the pretext to the question 6 and then the actual parts 7) you have to show that $\rho*x = x*\rho$. My trouble is I keep finding that $G$ has to be abelian for this to work but according to the TA that's not necessary. How do you show with an arbitrary group, not just an abelian group, that these are equal? I've gotten to the point that I know I have to show that:

$g_{1}g_{2} + ... + g_{1}g_{k} = g_{2}g_{1} + ... + g_{k}g_{1}$

and

$g_{2}g_{1} + ... + g_{2}g_{k} = g_{1}g_{2} + ... + g_{k}g_{2}$

$\vdots$

$g_{k}g_{1} + ... + g_{k}g_{k-1} = g_{1}g_{k} + ... + g_{k-1}g_{k}$

I'm not entirely sure that's right but that's what I have so far.

Comment: Ask yourself, how many times does each element of $G$ appear on each side of each of your $k$ equations?

Comment: Just toss it into your product formula.

Comment: The first equation can factor into g_{1}(g_{2} + ... + g_{k}) = (g_{2} + ... g_{k})g_{1} for example if that's what you mean. I'm still not sure then what to do because you can't cancel.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since $G=\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$, every element $x\in RG$ actually has the form

$$x=\sum_{k=1}^nr_kg_k$$

for some $r_1,\ldots,r_n\in R$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\rho x&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^ng_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^nr_kg_k\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{g_ig_j=g_k}1_R\cdot r_j\right)g_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{g_ig_j=g_k}r_jg_k\;.\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

Now $g_ig_j=g_k$ if and only if $g_i=g_kg_j^{-1}$. This means that for each $j$, the term $r_jg_k$ occurs exactly once in the inner summation in $(1)$, and hence

$$\rho x=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nr_jg_k=\sum_{k=1}^nrg_k=r\sum_{k=1}^ng_k=rx\;,$$

where $r=r_1+\ldots+r_n$.

Now calculate $x\rho$ in similar fashion and compare results.

Comment: Right I should have thought about the fact that $g_i=g_kg_j^{-1}$. This is a great explanation thanks I think I have it now.

Comment: @Sam: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $x=r_1h_1+r_2h_2+\dots r_mh_m$ then $x\rho=\rho x=\sum_{i=1}^n(r1+r2+\dots+r_n)g_i$.

Think about how $r_1h_1$ affects each coefficient in the product (use the fact that the function defined by $f(g')=gg'$ is bijective in a group, for any fixed $g$).

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes from the misleading "$+$" notation for elements of $RG$. In fact, $RG$ is the set of maps of finite support from $G$ to $R$; that is, maps from $G$ to $R$ so that only finitely many elements of $G$ are mapped to non-$0_R$ elements in $R$. The notation $r_1g_1 + \cdots$ simply means $g_1$ is mapped to $r_1$, ...  Now: If $G$ is finite, $\rho$ is the map that assigns $1_R$ to all elements of $G$. Now $g \rho$ is just a reshuffling of mapping all the elements of $G$ to $1_R$, so $g\rho = \rho$, and similarly $\rho g = \rho$ - for EVERY $g \in G$. Essentially, all that's behind this problem is that multiplication by a fixed element of $G$, either on the left or on the right, is just a bijection of $G$ onto itself.